# Android BLE Notification Device WakeUp

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, rxandroidble, bluetooth-peripheral

I'm using rxAndroidBLE to develop a companion app for a BLE peripheral that triggers alarms on the device.

The problem I'm having is that the notifications for the alarm are not properly triggering the alarm on the device. I'm guessing that it's something with the notification not properly waking up the device.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: On which device do you have the alarm, the Android device or the peripheral device? And what do you mean with "not properly triggering the alarm"?

Comment: The alarm notification is sent from the peripheral at a designated time, which I receive on the device in a foreground service, and then triggers an intent to launch an activity that displays the alarm status to the user (and plays a sound) on the device. From what I can tell, the notification from the peripheral is not waking the device, and so it therefore is not properly launching the intent. Is there a way to ensure that a notification from a BLE peripheral will wake the device?

Comment: It will surely wake the CPU and your app will process the callback. If your intent works and unlocks the screen is a completely different question unrelated to BLE. So, please use logcat or any other method to check if the onCharacteristicChanged callback is actually called. You can simulate the intent-activity thing without BLE by having a postDelayed for maybe 10 seconds somewhere you can easily start, then just lock the screen and see if it soon turns on with your alarm activity.